# How to manage facebook data deletion url or callback

Tags: react-native, facebook

I just wanted to know how to create Facebook data deletion URL. I have a react native app, and for this to work do I just need a "Delete Account" option in my app that deletes the Facebook user data from my database. I'm not sure how this works, could someone let me know how to implement Facebook data deletion URL or even a callback?

My app allows users to make likes, and post messages will I have to delete all the likes and messages from my database during this deletion process if the user is signed in through Facebook?

I tried the code in the answer but i get this error:

```
im getting this:
{"error": {"code": 10, "fbtrace_id": "xxx", "message": "(#10) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.", "type": "OAuthException"}}
```

Comment: First of all, you will need a _server-side_ endpoint to process the data Facebook will send you. Anything purely client-side won't help you here.

Comment: _"will I have to delete all the likes and messages from my database during this deletion process"_ - first and foremost, you will need to delete any data about them you got _from_ Facebook. Whether any data you created on your end, also needs to be deleted, depends on the specifics - what kind of data; will it still be necessary to keep the rest of the site working for other users, either as-is, or perhaps only in anonymized form; what did your privacy policy say about how you handle this to begin with, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

   const handleDataDeletion = () => {
        // Perform data deletion logic
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
          const { accessToken } = data || {};
          if (accessToken) {
            fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${accessToken.userId}?access_token=${accessToken}`)
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(json => {
                // Delete the user's Facebook data
                console.log(json);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
        });
      };
```

This code not tested but you can do this way and here used older facebook sdk library

Comment: Thanks for the information appreciated ill try it, but what do I put in the data deletion URL or callback within Facebooks details?

Comment: and do i need the graph api to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can find more graph api to do you task